# Projected normal distribution: projecting 3D vectors perturbed by Gaussian noise.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, vectors, normal-distribution

I am interested in the following problem.

Consider a unit vector $\hat{u}$ in 3D and the perturbed vector $\vec{v} = \hat{u} + \vec{x}$, where $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\sigma)$, that is, the vector is perturbed by a random vector sampled from a normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. I am now interested in the distribution of
\begin{equation}
\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\hat{u}}{\|\vec{v}\|} = \cos\theta,
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ is the angle between the original and perturbed vector. In particular I am interested in the case where $\sigma \ll 1$.

By running numerical simulations I find that $1-\cos\theta$ is distributed according to an exponential distribution when $\sigma\ll 1$. I am interested in a derivation of, or argument for, this result. If there is a way to relate the variance of the normal distribution to the mean of the exponential distribution that would be even better!

I believe this problem is related to the projected normal distribution. See e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3773532/
However, they consider the general case an in particular when effectively $\sigma>1$. From this general result I am having a hard time finding the limit $\sigma \ll 1$.

Comment: This is essentially because the radial component squared in $u^\perp$ direction is exponentially distributed (being the sum of two iid zero mean Gaussian, recall Box-Muller transform).

Comment: @user10354138, would you mind expanding on this? I am not familiar with the Box-Muller transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the name of the variables because I want to use $x_i$ for the coordinate axes.

Very briefly: Assuming independence of your $x_i$, which I'm going to call $\varepsilon_i$.  Since $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2I_3)$ is radially symmetric, we may rotate and pick $u$ to be on the positive $x_1$-axis.  Then $v=u+\varepsilon$ gives
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{u\cdot v}{\lvert v\rvert}=\frac{1+\varepsilon_1}{\sqrt{(1+\varepsilon_1)^2+(\varepsilon_2^2+\varepsilon_3^2)}}
$$
or equivalently (since $\sigma\ll 1$)
\begin{align*}
\tan\theta&=\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon_2^2+\varepsilon_3^2}}{1+\varepsilon_1}=\sqrt{\varepsilon_2^2+\varepsilon_3^2}(1+O_p(\sigma))\\
\implies\theta&=\sqrt{\varepsilon_2^2+\varepsilon_3^2}(1+O_p(\sigma))
\end{align*}
So
$$
1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2(\theta/2)=\frac12(\varepsilon_2^2+\varepsilon_3^2)(1+O_p(\sigma)).
$$
Standard result says the sum of squares of two independent $N(0,1)$s is the exponential distribution with mean $2$.  So $\frac12(\varepsilon_2^2+\varepsilon_3^2)$ is $\frac12\sigma^2$ times an exponential of mean $2$.  Since exponential distribution is closed under scaling by positive factor, this gives exponential with mean $\sigma^2$ as the approximate distribution of $1-\cos\theta$.